# removing %20 from url and replacing with - sign in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

i'm getting an %20 instead of space in $method->url how to replace them.

```
 <?= anchor("controller/method/{$method->id}/{$method->url}",character_limiter($article->title,100)) ?>
```

Comment: If you are looking for an slug this will help you

http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Answer (score 2):

You can't replace `%20` from URL. Easiest way is replace spaces into Hyphens `-`

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $method->url);?>
```

So in URL it's looks like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/controller/method/43671993/removing-20-from-url-and-replacing-with-sign-in-codeigniter
```

Comment: ashraf, are you using url_encode() ? Might be the reason

Comment: Thanks, str_replace(' ', '-', $method->url) this code is the best